# Initial permission error to ssh key with debian server

Tags: debian, ssh, permissions, sshd

I have a debian server on my pc and want to ssh connect form my mac.

First of all I generated an ssh key via

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

in my mac, then tried to copy public key to server with

```
ssh-copy-id <server_ip>
```

but got `Permission denied, please try again`.

I tried

```
ssh-copy-id <root@server_ip>
```

even

```
ssh-copy-id <myusername_in_server@server_ip>
```

and still get same error.

Also I updated `sshd_config` in my server with following changes:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PublickeyAuthentication yes
```

and restarted the debian server with

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

and tried all steps again but got same error.

Its wired I can switch between users on server with their password but when I use that password for mac connection got permission error, so the password is correct.

Is there another way to copy this key and put in debian server manually?

Comment: do delete the ~/.ssh directory, do `chmod 700 ~` and run ssh-copy-id again.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro delete ssh directory in server or client?

Comment: Client, you do not want to delete your private key. `chmod 700 ~` in both the client and the server. Serverside, do also `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Comment: Are those `<` and `>` characters part of the actual command that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

To manually copy a key, inside the ".ssh" directory of the user's profile, you have to create the directory "authorized_keys", with 600 permissions.
Then paste your public key into the authorized_keys file

-$ mkdir ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

-$ chmod 600

-$ vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

And paste the pub key from your local machine.

To correctly check the errors you can check /var/log/auth.log

Dont forget set your sshd_config with:

LogLevel DEBUG